# How to pass value from one window to another

Tags: wpf, vb.net

How do I pass a value from one a variable to a textbox after it's set? On winforms, I used to use form1.textbox1.text = variable in winforms.

I set, and get the variable from this...

```
 Public Shared Property containerstring() As String
        Get
            Return m_containerstring
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_containerstring = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Shared m_containerstring As String
```

Basically, I have a window... where the user chooses a variable, this variable is then set @ containerstring. When this form closes, I wanted to push this variable to the currently open window's textbox.

I'm new to WPF, forgive the noobness.

This is how I do it for a window, and this works perfectly... for windows. I'm looking to do the same thing with a control.

```
   Dim strWindowToLookFor As String = GetType(MainWindow).Name

            Dim win = ( _
                  From w In Application.Current.Windows _
                  Where DirectCast(w, Window).GetType.Name = strWindowToLookFor _
                  Select w _
               ).FirstOrDefault
            If win IsNot Nothing Then
                DirectCast(win, MainWindow).Title = SelectedContainer
            End If
```

Comment: I don't know vb so I cant help you too much, but  basically you can define an event on your App object.  Window one will subscribe to the event and window two will raise the event, passing the desired value or object.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Window closing Event like :

`this.Closed += MyWindow_Closed;`

and then set your variable in the corresponding method.

```
private void MyWindow_Closed()
{
    TextBox1.Text = a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a PubSubEvent which is available in Prism.Events. This will allow you to subscribe to events.

```
    Using Prism.Events;
```

define your Event.

```
   public class MyEvents : PubSubEvent<object>
   {
     public MyEvents();
   }
```

In your first window or code behind

```
    [Import]
    public IEventAggregator EventAggregator
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

and you can use this property in your program to send whatever value you want to send.
For example

```
private void MyWindow_Closed()
{
   MyEvents myEvents = EventAggregator.GetEvent<MyEvents>();
   myEvents.Publish(yourvalue);
}
```

Once you have publised you can Subscribe to the same event in any other part of your program like this.

```
  MyEvents myEvents = EventAggregator.GetEvent<MyEvents>();
  myEvents.Subscribe(MyEventMethod, ThreadOption.UIThread, true);
```

and get your data here

```
  void MyEventMethod(object obj)
  {
    // do wharever you want
  }
```